# Handling a pool of dedicated long lived process behind a wcf service

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service to create that will have to pilot a desktop process for the remote client. 
 My limitations are :
  - the wcf service could not handle more 100 simultaneous desktop process concurrently.
  - the wcf service have to be protected so that a problem with one desktop process does not stop the server to respond to other clients.

Here is the scenario that would have thought to put in place :
 - the wcf service will have a pool of 100 operators to handle that could take the work for the remote client.
 - First the remote client should ask for a transactionId and if possible an operator is assigned from the pool with this transactid
 - Then the client would call various operations with his transactionId on the wcf service that will delegate the work to the assigned operator and would send back the result of the operation to the client.
 - When the operator is assigned : it would have to survive between the different remote clients calls (or for a certain time limit in order to protect the server from resource exhaustion) 
 - finally the client would call the wcf service to notify that the work is done, and the operator would go back to the operator's pool.

As of now I have create the operator's pool and managed to make the assigned operator do his work on a dedicated thread. But I have some performance issues and sometime the wcf service crash because of the work done for a remote client...
 Is there any strategy/pattern or common way to put this kind of architecture in place ?

Comment: Your performance problems and crashes could be caused by many different things. If you don't know how to debug your own code, you need to ask how to debug in general, not how we can debug it for you.

Comment: @FrankHileman : the question is not why I have some performance issues or crash : but how to use the wcf stack and securize a pool of subprocess  dedicated to each client session... and how to prevent any client session to crash the whole process...

Comment: WCF is simply for communication. You have to use all the usual multithreaded server precautions.